# MongoDB 3.2 BI Connector to Tableau: Invalid username or password

Tags: mongodb

Running MongoDB 3.2.4 Enterprise on RHEL 6.7.
Running Tableau 9.3 on Windows 7.
Following https://docs.mongodb.org/bi-connector/installation/ to install MongoDB BI Connector to connect MongoDB 3.2 on linux to Tableau 9.3 on windows.

Step 6:
In Tableau Desktop 9.3 running on my Windows laptop,
Data > New Data Source > PostgreSQL
In the popup “PostgreSQL Connection” window, I type in the required info
Server:  mymongodb32server
Port:  27027
Database:  mybiuser2
Authentication:  User Name and Password
Username:  mybiuser2
Password:  abcdefg
[ ] Require SSL
After I click “OK”, it pops up an error window:
An error occurred while communicating with the PostgreSQL Database data source ‘mybiuser2’.  Invalid username or password.
* Communication closed during authentication; Socket has been closed.
* Invalid username or password.

I used the username and password created in step 2. All steps below are done on linux machine.
Step 2:
% mongobiuser create mybiuser2 mongodb://mymongodb32server.[MY_COMPANY_NAME].com:27027/[MY_DB_NAME]
password: abcdefg
Step 3:
% mongodrdl --host mymongodb32server.[MY_COMPANY_NAME].com --port 27027 -d [MY_DB_NAME] -o schema.drdl
Step 4:
% mongobischema import mybiuser2 schema.drdl
Step 5:
I don't need to install PostgreSQL driver since Tableau 9.3 installs it by default.

Please advise if I'm doing something wrong in these steps resulting in that invalid username or password error.

Thanks.
HL

Answer (score 0):

just stumbled upon the same issue.
It seems as if they create the user 'mongodb' instead of the one you provide in step 2, but the password there is used.
So 'mongobischema import mongodb schema.drdl' will work.

However, there seems to be yet another error in the documentation. The step which registers the PostgreSQL 'foreign data wrapper' is missing. In my case I got an 'mongodb_proxy_server' does not exist error. I found this page here which contains some explanation about what to do: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html.
Nevertheless, they seem to intend to use some Python based fdw, but I have no Python knowledge so I got stuck here. If you have some Python knowledge I hope you can continue from here :-/
I also tried this one here: https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw which looked very promising. But when trying to register the fdw I get this error: 'could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/mongo_fdw.o": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/mongo_fdw.o: only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded'.
So dead end here as well.

If you are able to process pls. share.
Many thanks,
Roman